# Play framework JSON - how to create constant Reads

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a model case class in my app and that class has an optional field that I'm never getting from my source API (in this case called `pictureUrl`)

```
case class User(email: String, pictureUrl: Option[String])
```

How can I write Reads that would fill pictureUrl with `None`? So far I'm my implementation looks like:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

object User {
  implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
    (JsPath \ "email").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "nonexistinglongstring").readNullable[String]
  )(User.apply _)
```

Which works but it's ugly and it's searching for `"nonexistinglongstring"`

I'm using playframework 2.3.x